# concurrent.futures does not work on ubuntu 18.04 and centosos 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I created a command line interface to run a simulation written in python (3.8). I added an option to launch several simulations at once using concurrent.futures and specifically ProcessPoolExecutor.This is my first experience with this package and I'm having problems. The code I created works perfectly in windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04 (on wsl2). But fail when I launch it in ssh server (CentosOS 7) and on ubuntu 18.04.
The exception I get is: `BrokenProcessPool`.
I also noticed one thing, when I launch my code asking for a less heavy workload and therefore taking less time, it goes perfectly. The code fails exclusively with heavy workloads, (e.g. simulations with numerous parameters). This suggests that there is some sort of timeout time. I have already tried using different methods of creating processes: ("fork", "spawn" and "forkserver"), always the same error. The exception is not related to the simulation code, I've already done numerous tests to make sure that's not the case.
Below is a minimal example of my code (I can't paste an entire simulation consisting of 6 different modules so for simplicity the simulation is "do something").

modes.py

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Executor
from concurrent.futures import as_completed
import pickle
from model import Simulation


class Mode:
    def __init__(self, num_workers):
        self.num_workers = num_workers
        self.args = [{"key": "arg"} ,
                     {"key1": "arg"}]

    def simulate(self):
        result = Simulation() #do something
        with open("location", "wb") as file:
            pickle.dump(result, file)
        return "Saved"


    def run_p(self):
        with Executor(max_workers=self.num_workers) as executor:
            for out in as_completed([executor.submit(self.simulate, args) for args in self.args]):
                print(out.result())
```

main.py

```py
from .modes import Mode

def go():
    mode = Mode(num_workers=5)
    mode.run_p()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    go()
```

My question in a nutshell is: what I need to do for my code to work in both centosOS 7 and windows, using ProcessPoolExecutor? Any suggestions are appreciated! Thank you all for your help.

```
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

Comment: Method `simulate` has the wrong signature; it should be something like `def simulate(self, args):`. I don't know how this even runs.

Comment: Did you read the question?  Quoting from my own question that you should have read if you wanted to help "Below is a minimal example of my code (I can't paste an entire simulation consisting of 6 different modules so for simplicity the simulation is "do something")."

Comment: Do you have enough memory on the servers where it fails? Don't set `max_workers` manually. You should also check the logs and `dmesg` for `OOM`.

Comment: Thanks, are you talking about virtual memory or free disk space?

Comment: Ok, thanks, it's an Out of memory! So, to solve it at this point I should decrease the number of workers. correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processes are most likely killed by [OOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory) due to low memory on the server:

[BrokenProcessPool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool):

> Derived from BrokenExecutor (formerly RuntimeError), this exception
> class is raised when one of the workers of a ProcessPoolExecutor has
> terminated in a non-clean fashion (**for example, if it was killed
> from the outside**).

You can confirm this by checking the logs and `dmesg` output.

I would also don't recommend changing the `max_workers` manually. The default value ([os.cpu_count()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py#L589)) is usually good enough and there is no point to set this to a number greater than available CPUs for a CPU bound workload as it will actually slow down the performance due to context switching etc.